# SQL Login page bypassing

Tags: sql, authentication

I am having simple SQL query like below :

```
SELECT * FROM LOGINDETAILS WHERE
USERNAME='".$USERNAME."' AND
PASSWORD='".$PASSWORD."';
```

whenever i am using `'+0#` as user name in login field, i am able to bypass login and i wanna know why it is really happening.

Any help appreciate..!

Comment: You most likely need to use prepared statements, that will prevent users from injecting SQL in your query and circumventing it.

Comment: I wanna know why that payload is able to bypass login query. Does +0 value have any meaning in SQL

Comment: run the query yourself and see the results. Additionally, you should be hashing passwords and using prepared statements. plain text is a big nono

Comment: I executed the query it's returning more than zero rows from table. I dont know how 0 value returning more than zero rows from database.